# How can I unit test that an async Task was awaited?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous

I need to unit test a method that looks roughly like this:

```
public async Task DoStuffAsync()
{
    var tasks = { dependency.FooAsync(), dependency.BarAsync() };

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

My first approach (using Moq) was like this:

```
dependency.Setup(d => d.FooAsync()).Returns(Task.FromResult(default(object)));
dependency.Setup(d => d.BarAsync()).Returns(Task.FromResult(default(object)));

await systemUnderTest.DoStuffAsync();

dependency.Verify(d => d.FooAsync(), Times.Once);
dependency.Verify(d => d.BarAsync(), Times.Once);
```

But this won't do, since if I change the method to something dumb like this:

```
public async Task DoStuffAsync()
{
    var tasks = { dependency.FooAsync(), dependency.BarAsync() };

    await tasks[0];
}
```

the test won't fail. How do I assert that the tasks were awaited?

EDIT:

I think this solution to this problem could be analogous to mine:
let's say I want to test this method for failure, i.e. one of the tasks throws and I want to assert that the exception is propagated. I need to check that for all the tasks, but there could be a dozen tasks awaited by `Task.WhenAll`. I'd then have to write a dozen tests, each of them would have a different, single task throw an exception, to make sure that all of them are correctly propagated. And writing a dozen same-y tests doesn't sound like a good thing. If I could just assert that all the tasks are awaited - that would solve my problem, as I can trust the async framework to propagate if an error occurs.

Comment: why **wouldn't** the they be awaited? This seems like a pointless test. Your testing an implementation detail. You should assume the class is a black box and test inputs and outputs only. The fact that it's async or not is irrelevant. By doing this your actively harming your ability to refactor this code at a later date.

Comment: If I just assume the method is correct then all tests are pointless.
Also I ommited any logic that goes between the calls and parameters the `FooAsync` and `BarAsync` get from `DoStuffAsync` to illustrate my problem without unnecessary noise. The method has to be tested anyway, but my test does not fail when the method does something wrong, so it's a bad test.

Comment: What you really want to test here is if `FooAsync` and `BarAsync` are called. Not that you waited. Use mocking to do this. Or better yet, return a valid result and test that.

Comment: Whether or not the tasks are awaited (as opposed to simply started) is invisible to the caller, so it's not surprising a mock wouldn't be able to tell either. If it *isn't* invisible to the caller, it would be because something fails if we proceed without waiting for the tasks to complete. That's the logic you'd want to isolate and test, and that may require something more sophisticated than a test for just this one method.

Comment: If you test the await all you are validating is that the framework is doing its job. I would argue that the scope of your test here is too small. You need to expand the unit under test here to more than just that method by the sounds of it, in order to be able to effectively test an output for a given input.

Comment: How about if I returned the `Task.WhenAll` at the end instead of awaiting it and tested if it contains all the called tasks? And is there a way to check that?

Comment: It is actually a possibility for the Tasks to be complete before being awaited in which case no await will happen, it will be synchronous. So, you can never really be sure something is awaited even though it may be extremely likely.

Comment: Or maybe return the enumerable all together and WaitAll in the caller? Would that be a better solution? Though it would be nice to find out if the caller waits for the tasks to be completed anyway.

Comment: I don't want to test the async framework. In my example the `tasks[1]` task is running wild and not awaited, it could crash or throw an exception that will never be handled, and the test will pass. That's what I want to test - that my method doesn't create any 'dangling', not awaited tasks. I could make one of the tasks throw an exception and assert that it's propagated, but then what if I have 10 tasks in my `WhenAll`? I'd have to make a separate test for each failure!

Comment: If finding unobserved tasks globally is a goal, it may be better to set up `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` and invoke explicit `GC.Collect`s in the `[TestCleanup]`. Doing this for every possible task created in every possible method is, as you've observed, way too involved (and beyond the scope of a test proper, as it requires intimate knowledge of how exactly the method is implemented to know what tasks it creates).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You give very little context (programming is all about context :)).
In you particular case if you want check that `DoStuffAsync` await all tasks returned by dependencies throw exceptions and await for them

For .NET 4.5.1 create helper method to create task with an exception.

```
static Task CreateTaskWithException(string exceptionMessage) 
{
    var taskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    var exception = new Exception(exceptionMessage);

    taskSource.SetException(exception);

    return taskSource.Task;
}
```

If you have multiple dependencies you can test for await - you can simple test all of them at once

```
dependency.Setup(d => d.FooAsync()).Returns(CreateTaskWithException("Foo"));
dependency.Setup(d => d.BarAsync()).Returns(CreateTaskWithException("Bar"));
dependency.Setup(d => d.FizzBuzzAsync()).Returns(CreateTaskWithException("FizzBuzz"));

var expectedErrors = new[] { "Foo", "Bar", "FizzBuzz" };
string[] actualErrors = null;
try
{
    DoStuffAsync().Wait();
    Assert.Fail("DoStuffAsync should throw exception");
}
catch(AggregateException exception)
{
    actualErrors = exception.InnerExceptions.Select(ex => ex.Message);
}

actualErrors.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);
```

Test will fail if you not awaiting all tasks.

```
public async Task DoStuffAsync()
{
    var tasks = { dependency.FooAsync(), dependency.BarAsync() };
    reutrn Task.WhenAll(tasks.Skip(1));
    // Test fail with message:
    // Expected subject to be a collection with 2 item(s), but {"Bar"}
    // contains 1 item(s) less than {"Foo", "Bar"}.        
}
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I use .NET 4.5.1, so no `CompletedTask` or `FromException` for me :(

This is actually a promising solution (see my edit), but the problem remains: what if I'm awaiting a dozen tasks and I need to verify that all are awaited?
Even now in this example I'd have to write two almost identical tests: in the first one `FooAsync` throws, in the second `BarAsync` throws. I feel like copy-pasting tests is not a good practice.

Comment: @V0ldek, in .net 4.5 you can create your own `CompletedTask` and `FromException` methods - see updated answer.

Comment: @V0ldek, for dozen dependencies calls, simple throw exceptions for all of them with different messages and assert them on catch - see updated answer.